# Save user session with HttpSession

Tags: spring-mvc, session, httpsession

I have a Spring-boot back end and wish to save my user's session upon login in order to re-use his information further down the line.

This is how I try to do it so far:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/login")
public ResponseEntity<UserInfoMessage> loginUser(@RequestBody UserInfoMessage userInfoMessage, HttpServletRequest request) {
    UserInfoMessage user = mapper.map(userService.login(mapper.map(userInfoMessage)));

    // If our login was a success
    if (user != null) {
        // Save user session
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("user", user);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(mapper.map(userService.login(mapper.map(userInfoMessage))), HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(mapper.map(userService.login(mapper.map(userInfoMessage))), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Where `UserInfoMessage` is a model that stores info such as my user's e-mail, name etc.

Here a `session.getAttribute("user");` is working.

But when I try to retrieve it in another controller it is null:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ProjectInfoMessage createProject(@RequestBody ProjectInfoMessage projectInfoMessage, HttpServletRequest request) {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    System.out.println("User is: " + session.getAttribute("user")); // null

    return mapper.map(projectService.createProject(mapper.map(projectInfoMessage), (UserInfoMessage)session.getAttribute("user")));
}
```

What am I not understanding in session handling?

Comment: Try to annotate your controllers with `@SessionAttributes(value="user")`

Comment: But I thought `@SessionAttributes` only worked for one controller

Comment: You can annotate more than one controller. You can also use `@SessionAttribute` (without "s") as a method argument to retrieve your user. `createProject(@SessionAttribute("user")UserInfoMessage user)`

Comment: `@SessionAttributes` does not seem to work, my object is still `null`.

Comment: What happens if you declare your session as a method argument using HttpSession interface? : `loginUser(@RequestBody UserInfoMessage userInfoMessage, HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session)` then add your user. This behavior seems strange, didn't you disable session management in your configuration?

Comment: I have added `HttpSession session` as a parameter to my login method and project creation method and removed the `HttpServletRequest` in both, I set in one controller and get in the other and the value of my user is still null. I don't recall having disabled session management in my conf.